# Firebase Call to the dynamic Reference not giving proper output

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, chat

i am creating a chat application for the browser using angular 1 and ionic 1

here is my controller and view for that
the problem is when the new message comes in the selected room which is current room watch variable and below console giving me proper output but that same method getting called twice giving me proper output at fist call but after that he gives me main node output.

```
    $scope.firstLoad='';
    $scope.directLoad='';
    $scope.text = "Tap on name to open chat !";
    $scope.myUid = localStorage.uid;
    $scope.rooms = [];
    $scope.roomsfound = 0;
    $scope.roomswait = 1;

    $scope.name = "";

    $scope.number = "";
    $scope.currentRoomId="";
    $scope.is_select_user = 0;
    $scope.loadDetails = function (roomId, contactName, phone, name) {
        $timeout(function () {
           $scope.firstLoad=false;
        },2000);
    $rootScope.showLoading("loadchat");
    $scope.currentRoomId="";
    $scope.name = "";
    $scope.number = "";
    $scope.name = name;
    $scope.number = phone[0] == '1' ? phone.slice(1) : phone;/*to stipe out 1 from the phone number in view*/
    $scope.is_select_user = 1;
    $scope.roomName = "Chat";
    $scope.chats = [];
    $scope.chats.length = 0;
    $scope.roomId = '';

    $scope.roomId = roomId;
    $scope.roomName = contactName;
    firebase.database().ref('messages/' + $scope.roomId).once('value', function (data) {
        $timeout(function () {
            var tempArr = [];
            data.forEach(function (data) {
                tempArr.push({
                    key: data.key,
                    content: data.val().message,
                    createdAt: data.val().timestamp,
                    from: data.val().sendBy,
                    to: data.val().sentTo,
                    direction: data.val().direction,
                    status: data.val().status,
                    type: data.val().type
                })
            });
            $scope.chats = tempArr;

        });
    });

    $scope.currentRoomId= $scope.roomId;

    console.log("In Load Details "+$scope.currentRoomId);
    if($scope.firstLoad == false){
        firebase.database().ref('rooms/' + $scope.myUid +'/'+$scope.roomId ).update({
            isRead:'true'
        })
    }
    $scope.Scroll_top();
    $rootScope.hideLoading("loadchat");
}
    /*Live Chat Listner for Current Room*/
    $scope.$watch(
                "currentRoomId",
                function handleMessageChange( newValue, oldValue ) {
    $timeout(function () {

    firebase.database().ref('messages/'+$scope.currentRoomId+'/').on('value', function (data) {
    console.log('messages/'+$scope.currentRoomId);
        if($scope.currentRoomId != ""){ 
            var liveChatArr = [];
            $scope.chats = [];


                data.forEach(function (data) {
                    liveChatArr.push({
                        key: data.key,
                        content: data.val().message,
                        createdAt: data.val().timestamp,
                        from: data.val().sendBy,
                        to: data.val().sentTo,
                        direction: data.val().direction,
                        status: data.val().status,
                        type: data.val().type
                    })
                });
                $scope.chats = [];
                $scope.chats.length=0;
                if( $scope.chats.length == 0)
                    $scope.chats=liveChatArr ;
                else{
                    $scope.chats = [];
                    $scope.chats.length=0;
                    $scope.chats=liveChatArr ;
                }
            $scope.Scroll_top();
        }    
    });
},3000);        
});
    /*End Live Chat Listener*/
    /*Send New Message*/
$scope.data = {};
$scope.sendMessage = function (roomId, message, name, phone, contactName) {
    Chats.send(roomId, $scope.myUid, message);
    document.getElementById("mymsg").value = "";
    $scope.data.message='';
};
/* End Send New Message*/
    /* Live Room Listner*/
firebase.database().ref('rooms/' + $scope.myUid).orderByChild('lastMessageAt').on('value', function (data) {
    $scope.liverooms = [];
    $scope.liverooms.length = 0;
    $scope.rooms = [];
    $scope.rooms.length=0;
    $timeout(function () {

        var unique = function(origArr) {
            //console.log(origArr);
            var newArr = [];
            var origLen = origArr.length;
            var found, x, y;

            for (x = 0; x < origLen; x++) {
                //console.log(x);
                found = undefined;
                for (y = 0; y < newArr.length; y++) {
                    if (origArr[x] === newArr[y]) {
                        found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!found) {
                    newArr.push(origArr[x]);
                }
            }
            return newArr;
        }

        data.forEach(function (data) {
            var ref=firebase.database().ref('rooms/' + $scope.myUid);
            var key = data.ref.key;
            var fields = key.split('_');
            var len = fields.length;
            var mobile = fields[len - 1];
            $scope.liverooms.push({
                roomId: key,
                contactName: data.val().contactName,
                contactfName: (data.val().contactName.split(' '))[0],
                lastMessage: data.val().lastMessage,
                lastMessageAt:  data.val().lastMessageAt,
                lastMessageDirection: data.val().lastMessageDirection,
                phone: mobile[0] == '1' ? mobile.slice(1) : mobile, 
                isRead:data.val().isRead
            });
        }); 
        $scope.rooms = [];
        $scope.rooms.length=0;
        if( $scope.rooms.length == 0 ){
            $scope.rooms=unique($scope.liverooms).reverse();
        }else{
            $scope.rooms = [];
            $scope.rooms.length=0;
            $scope.rooms=unique($scope.liverooms).reverse();
        }
        //console.log($scope.rooms);
    });
    $scope.roomswait = 0;
    if ($scope.rooms.length > 0) {
        $scope.roomsfound = 1;
    }
});
/* End Live Room Listner*/
```

**VIEW**

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="col-lg-3 searchmain-box">
            <br>
            <div class="input-group col-sm-6 col-xs-3 col-md-12 mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0">
                <div class="input-group-addon radius-left search-box"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control radius-right search-box" ng-model="search" id="inlineFormInputGroup" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <br>

            <div class="col-md-12 text-center" ng-show="roomswait == 1">
                <img src="img/loading.gif" width="30">
                <br>
                <h5 class="text-white">Please Wait.. Loading Chats</h5>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group user-list" ng-show="roomsfound == 0">
                <li class="list-group-item user-list" style="cursor:pointer;outline:none" ng-if="room" ng-repeat="room in rooms| filter:search " ng-init="($first && firstLoad) ? loadDetails(room.roomId, room.contactName + ' (' + room.phone + ')', room.phone, room.contactName) : ''" type="item-text-wrap" ng-click="loadDetails(room.roomId, room.contactName + ' (' + room.phone + ')', room.phone, room.contactName)">
                    <!--<li class="list-group-item user-list" ng-repeat="room in rooms| orderBy:'lastMessageAt':true | filter:search"  type="item-text-wrap" ng-click="loadDetails(room.roomId, room.contactName + ' (' + room.phone + ')', room.phone, room.contactName)">-->
                    <div class="user-profile" ng-if="room.contactName == name && room.phone == number">
                        <span><img src="img/liveicon.png"></span>&nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <div class="user-name" >
                        <h4 class="ma-0" ng-class="{'user-live':room.contactName == name && room.phone == number , 'dark-text':(room.contactName != name || room.phone != number) && room.isRead != 'false' , 'not_read':room.isRead == 'false'}" >
                            {{room.contactName}}
                            <span class="live-chaticon"></span>
                        </h4>
                        <span style="float:left"><img src="img/phone.png"/></span>
                        <p class="user-phoneno mb-0" style="padding:5px;margin-left: 16px;" ng-class="{'not_read':room.isRead == 'false'}">
                            {{room.phone| bcTelephone:'format'}}
                        </p> 

                        <p class="user-message mb-0" style="font-size: 12px;" ng-show="room.lastMsg != ''" ng-class="{'not_read':room.isRead == 'false', 'dark-text':room.isRead == 'true'}">
                            <span ng-if="room.lastMessageDirection == 'out'">You:</span> 
                            <span ng-if="room.lastMessageDirection == 'in'">{{room.contactfName}}:</span>
                            {{(room.lastMessage| limitTo: 20) + (room.lastMessage.length  > 20 ? '..' : '')}}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="user-time">
                        <p class="dark-text"> 
                            <span class="time2" ng-show="room.lastMessageAt != ''" am-time-ago="room.lastMessageAt"></span>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="recent-bg" block-ui="loadchat" style="width:61%;position:fixed;top:0;right:0;background-color:white">
            <div class="recent-order">
                <!--                <div class="recent-text ">
                                    <h4 class="user-name">{{name}} <span class="live-chaticon"></span></h4>
                                    <h5> <span style="float:left"><img src="img/phone.png"  height="20px"/></span> {{number| bcTelephone:'format'}} </h5>
                                </div>-->
                <div class="recent-text ">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <h4 class="user-name">{{name}} <span class="live-chaticon"></span></h4>
                            <!--<h5 class="user-number">{{number}} </h5>-->
                            <!--<h5 class="user-number"> {{number| bcTelephone:'format'}} </h5>-->

                            <h5> <span style="float:left"><img src="img/phone.png"  height="20px"/></span> {{number| bcTelephone:'format'}} </h5>
                        </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 pa-0">
                    <h5 ng-if="text != ''" class="text-center">{{text}}</h5>
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <div class="frame">
                            <div ng-show="chats.length != 0">
                                <ul class="message-box">
                                    <li ng-repeat="chat in chats| orderBy:'createdAt':false" ng-if="chat"  ng-class="{'pull-right default-user ': chat.direction == 'out','pull-left client-user':chat.direction != 'out'}">
                                        <p>{{chat.content}}  <br>
                                            <span style="font-size: 10px;" am-time-ago="chat.createdAt" ng-class="{'pull-right default-user': chat.direction == 'out','pull-left client-user':chat.direction != 'out'}"></span>
                                            <br>
                                            <span style="font-size: 10px; float: right" > {{chat.status}}</span>
                                        </p>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="message-sendbtn" style="position:fixed;width:61%" ng-show="is_select_user">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control message-control" id="mymsg" placeholder="Your message" ng-model="data.message" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" ng-enter="sendMessage(roomId, data.message, name, number, roomName)">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2" ng-click="sendMessage(roomId, data.message, name, number, roomName)"  ><img src="img/send-icon.png"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is My View 
[image]
I am getting issue when new message comes in node Contact list which is Room array getting double records and when i send message some time its not showing live status of message and some time it messes up with wrong node (Current Room)

By using on("value") method is getting called multiple times.

Kindly help me i am stuck here.